# Java Wildcard Import Statements

Tags: java, import, javafx, javafx-8

The top of my javaFX programs will usually look something like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

I was wondering if there's any way to simply import *everything* from javaFX using a statement like **import javafx.*;** or something similar. Otherwise, is there an easy way to find the required import statement for any new piece of the api that I learn?

Comment: The wildcard `*` will only import classes from the explicitly named package, not from any subpackages. In Eclipse, you can do Shift-Control-O to organize imports - it will suggest imports for any classes you use that are not resolved. (So you can basically type a class name and then hit Shift-Control-O and choose the import). I'm sure other IDEs have the same functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally its regarded as bad practice to bring in more than you need using wilcards. You can inadvertently use the wrong class. Classes are cleaner if you explicitly import what you need.
Regarding finding the import, most IDE's will assist you by suggesting a list of possible imports.

Comment: It may not be the best practice, but let's say I'm just working on a school assignment where a gui is a required, but unimportant component, and I don't want to bother with individual statements. Is there really no way to do this?

Comment: No. This is core Java. You have to import what you need at class or package level.

Comment: You could just fully qualify all the class names, of course, and not use any imports at all. But that would be less convenient, not more...

Answer (score 2):

As stated before, it is very bad practice import more then you actually need. And as a programming teacher I would personally mark a project down if it would do blanket imports...